# Is there a similar framework to Mockito for testing shared code or iOS code in a Kotlin MPP?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, kotlin-multiplatform

I'd like to use Mockito.verify() in common test code in a Kotlin multiplatform project. Is there a framework similar to Mockito for Kotlin MPP?

Comment: are you doing kotlin Native without using JVM ?

Comment: I'm evaluating Kotlin multiplatform project (MPP) to see if I can apply this architecture to my personal project, and wondering how shared code for testing could be written.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UIKit` in Kotlin

You can find the official Example Here

[Kotlin-Native: UIKit Example](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/tree/master/samples/uikit)

Interop XCTest

```
  language = Objective-C
  package = platform.XCTest
  headers = XCTest/XCTest.h

  headerFilter = XCTest/**
```

Then you can code like this using XCTest

```
  import platform.XCTest.XCTWaiter
  import platform.XCTest.XCTestExpectation
  .....
  .....
  XCTWaiter().waitForExpectations( ..... )
```

Answer (score 1):

For a mocking library, the short answer is no. There's some discussion of adding JS support to [Mockk](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/100), and I've seen some about Native, but I'm pretty sure neither is in progress.

Comment: At this point, I'd need one only for Android and iOS. JS is not a priority for now. So, how do you write a test for shared code by Android and iOS? It seems that test code can't be shared for now. Especially, I guess that instrumented tests for Android can't be shared with iOS.

Comment: there is no common unit test framework fully acknowledged your ask, You will end up in creating externalized scripts like test automation, which may not be treated unit testing, you can use reflection based approach, but professionally it will look bad

Comment: You can't use a mocking framework for common code to mock classes. You can use interfaces and create fake implementations. If a fully capable runtime mock library is required, you'll have difficulty, but this isn't really a thing in Swift either. There are some code gen ones, but there's no Mockito equivalent in Swift (for the same reasons). Not sure what kind of instrumentation tests you'd want to share. Easier to discuss with an example. In summary, tests can absolutely be shared now, but you won't be able to do everything in the same way.